# RSS Feed Broken - Limit?

Tags: rss, feed

Our RSS feed just stopped working and we get this error in chrome:

This page contains the following errors:
error on line 7938 at column 2: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

There is nothing important on that line other than some post text.

We use an RSS feed plugin to pull content and syndicate it on other sites. Because of this we have the number in "Syndication feeds show the most recent" set to 400. This means that it is showing 400 full posts/pages in the RSS feed. If I change number back to 200, the feed starts working. Set back to 400 and it breaks... Seems like we are hitting a limit somewhere.

I have checked for blank spaces in functions.php, wp-config.php, etc... all were fine.

Anyone have any ideas what might be going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Ok, nevermind... We figured out we can pull individual feeds for each categories and so we set the general overall limit back to 10. And here is function to override general limit.`<br/> function custom_rss_limits($limits) {
  if (is_feed() && is_category(‘category-slug’)) {
    // target a specific feed category and set a unique limit
                return "LIMIT 0, 20";
  } else {
    // It's not a feed; leave the normal LIMIT in place.
    return $limits;
  }
}
add_filter('post_limits', 'custom_rss_limits');<br/>`
Hopefully that helps someone.

Comment: You should add this as an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question :( Will delete comment and add there tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nevermind...

We figured out we can pull individual feeds for each categories and so we set the general overall limit back to 10. And here is function to override general limit.

`function custom_rss_limits($limits) { if (is_feed() && is_category(‘category-slug’)) { // target a specific feed category and set a unique limit return "LIMIT 0, 20"; } else { // It's not a feed; leave the normal LIMIT in place. return $limits; } } add_filter('post_limits', 'custom_rss_limits');`

Hopefully that helps someone.

Comment: Glad you got it to work... Please mark your awner as the right one.